# How to run Sub with parameter in Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have procedure in Excel VBA which is need range parameter and also will produce output range exactly in active cell.

The code looks like this :

```
Sub test(oSource as Range)
  Dim oTarget As Range
  Dim oCell As Range

  Set oTarget = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0))

  For Each oCell In oSource
    If oCell.Value <> "" Then
        oTarget.Activate

        oTarget.Offset(0, 0).Value = oCell.Text
        oTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Text

        Set oTarget = oTarget.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

How do i call this ? I already try using function like this

```
Function(SourceRange as Range)
   Call test(SourceRange)
End Function
```

But it not working because `test()` will produce range in the active cell and will replace the function, excel will give circular value warning. I cant register it in macro, the create button always disabled when i click play. So how i call this Sub ?

Comment: You never use the  `SourceRange` parameter that you pass to the sub in the first code. Do you understand how passing parameters work?

Comment: You changed your code after my comment. Let us know when you're done editing your code sample, so we all know what we're looking at.

Comment: @teylyn sorry, it's ok now.

Comment: you can't change another cells' content from within a function, even if you call a sub from it. If you want to manipulate cell contents try to use worksheet events instead of calling subs from UDFs. If you need more help, then please explain a bit more you objective.

Answer (score 0):

You call the first procedure by passing a range as the argument.

`test(ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1"))`

Comment: Can user change this without entering VBA ? Because some user who will use this is prefer run and choose source directly without entering VBA, they lack skill on it..